# generic xor swap in c# for different types

Tags: c#, generics, xor

I'm trying to make a function that can swap any 2 variables in c# whether they are reference or value types using the xor method. Would this work properly for that purpose?

```
public static void QuickSwap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(a, b) || (typeof(T).IsValueType && a == b))
        return;
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

Comment: This is an exercise in pointlessness. It was a cute trick, at one point in time, but these days you're better off writing clear, well structured code and letting the compilers worry about micro-optimizing and register allocations.

Comment: Why do you need to use the XOR method? If it is because you think this is quicker than alternatives (assumption based on the method name you've chosen) then the call to `typeof(T).IsValueType` will likely dwarf the actual XOR operations. Write a simple swap instead using a temporary variable, this way you don't need any special handling at all.

Comment: There's even a dedicated page on [Wikipedia discussing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm): "On modern CPU architectures, the XOR technique can be slower than using a temporary variable to do swapping" - so if you do persist in trying to do this, at least make sure to correct the name for the method.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile since there's no `^=` operator for `T`.

Comment: There's no equality operator instead, I suspect the OP knows all this and is just asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the [XOR operator in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) is only defined for [integral types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) and bool.

(There is no generic XOR operator on arbitrary types, since it would result in an invalid state, which contradicts the design goal of C# as a type-safe language: `myClass1 ^ myClass2` would point to an invalid memory location, and the result of `myStruct1 ^ myStruct2` would most likely be garbage as well.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write a function to swap two values. You can just use a tuple:

```
(a, b) = (b, a);
```